# Is there a way to stop computation and return an API call in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, promise

I've a stub on the api server that does some preprocessing before calling delegate.call() on the api.
I want to make sure that delegate.call() returns in 10s and if it doesn't I want to kill the computation and return.

I've been able to return after the timeout by wrapping delegate.call in a promise. But the play server still continues with the computation for that specific call. I don't want to waste resource thus I want to "cancel" the promise.

delegate.call returns a Promise, but there is no cancel method on that.

I'm using Java 7 in play framework.

Comment: `F.Promise` has few `timeout` methods to use. Can't you use them? Those methods are there since 2.1.x

Comment: Yes the timeouts are there. I've tried using them. But them problem is this just timeouts the promise. 
Let's say I've a call that does some computation for 100s. And I've a timeout for 5 seconds. Even though the call would return in 5 seconds, the computation on API server would keep on going for 95 more seconds. I want to kill the computation too.